# Validate Gherkin structure using Regex

Tags: regex, gherkin

### Background:

**I want a regular expression that can identify when a Gherkin statement is improperly written.** The text will be multi-line. Unfortunately I can not use a code solution to solve this, it must be PCRE regex.

Reading through the [Gherkin Keywords Documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/#keywords), it appears the correct structure order follows:

`Feature > Rule (optional) > Background (Optional) > Examples/Scenarios (Optional) that contains > [One or more](Example/Scenario) that contains > Given > [One or more of any] When|Then|But|(And/*)`

Notes:

- `Scenarios/Examples`, `Scenario/Example`, `AND/*` means they are aliases
- For clarity one or more `Scenario/Example` must exist with or without the `Scenarios/Examples` optional "container"

### Problem:

***I attempted to tackle this using the positive case (proper format match) with the plan to work on the negation once I got that working.***

I tried both non-capturing groups and negative look-aheads but without success. **For example the code below will match `Scenario/Example` in between `Rule` and `Background`** which should not work for the positive case. It appears my groups are too greedy? I am not sure how to fix it or if this should be solved in a different way.

Attempt with non-capturing groups:

```
(Feature:[\s\S]+?)(?:Rule:[\s\S]+?)?(?:Background:[\s\S]+?)?(Scenario:[\s\S]+?)(Given:[\s\S]+?)(When|Then|And|\*)[\s\S]*?((?=(Scenario|Feature|$)))
```

Partial attempt with negative look-aheads to test the beginning order:

```
(Feature:[\s\S]+)(?=(Rule:[\s\S]+)?)(?=(Background:[\s\S]+)?)(?=(Scenario:[\s\S]+)*)
```

Example proper Gherkin format:

```
Feature: Web Searching
  As a business analyst, I want to use a public search engine to find information.

Rule: The browser used must be X

Background:
 Given a user has an information need
 And the browser X is installed on their device
  
Scenario: Simple search
 Given a web browser is on the search page
 When the search phrase "stackoverflow" is entered
 Then results for "stackoverflow" are shown
 And the user can choose a result from a list
```

Comment: If you can't use any code, what is the tool/platform that you are using to validate these documents? Which regex flavor does it use?

Comment: This is going to be a much more complex regex. Already the first word could be a comment, not `Feature`. Not to start about the language header that could set an alternative keyword set...

Comment: you might be better to start from the grammar: https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/main/c/gherkin.berp

Comment: The flavor is PCRE

Comment: The purpose for this is to have users enter clear business requirements that can be tested against. The content will be submitted in a text form and will be used only for human consumption. The tool allows search of entries by regex. The tool is not something I own, so I am just trying to solve the regex part of this.

Therefore I don't think @trincot I need to worry about headers, or comment lines

Comment: *"and will be used only for human consumption"*: that would be an argument *for* inclusion of comments, not against. Machines don't need comments; humans do.

Comment: I just meant there will not be complex development logic that would need the inclusion of comments. The Scenarios should clearly define the intent.

Comment: You might use an approach like this https://regex101.com/r/CaGbo0/1 and then for the captured parts you can extend the logic if you want.

Comment: There are a lot of aspects to Gherkin that you could potentially check for; Regex is obviously going to be somewhat limited.  For inspiration have a look at https://github.com/racodond/sonar-gherkin-plugin

Answer (score 1):

String that doesn't match `%g` as a whole is just `^(?!%g$)`, that's it.

---

I was able to generate a matching regex with the following Dimava's regex grammar:

```
%0 = ^%e%Feature!%Rule!?%Background!?%Scenario!+$
%Feature! = Feature:%OptDesc!%Description!%e
%OptDesc! = \n|%ReqDesc!
%Description! = (?:%w\S.*\n)+

%Rule! = %wRule:%ReqDesc!%e
%ReqDesc! =  \S.*\n

%Background! = %wBackground:\n%Description2!%e
%Description2! = (?:%w%w\S.*\n)+

%Scenario! = %wScenario:%ReqDesc!%Given!%When!*%e
%Given! = %w%wGiven%ReqDesc!
%When! = %w%w(?:When|Then|And)%ReqDesc!

// indentation (two spaces)
%w =   
// empty lines
%e = \n*(?!\n)
```

resulting in regex

```
^\n*(?!\n)(?:Feature:(?:\n| \S.*\n)(?:  \S.*\n)+\n*(?!\n))(?:  Rule: \S.*\n\n*(?!\n))?(?:  Background:\n(?:    \S.*\n)+\n*(?!\n))?(?:  Scenario: \S.*\n    Given \S.*\n(?:    (?:When|Then|And) \S.*\n)*\n*(?!\n))+$
```

You may test it on https://regex101.com/r/hbLJc3/1
(you need to run the snippet in browser's console on regex101 page if you want to use the compiler)
If there are missing cases that you'd expect to work, add them into "Test cases" there and comment with updated regex101 link

---

I've updated to https://regex101.com/r/zmgSNK/1

```
%0 = ^%e%Feature!%Rule!?%Background!?%Scenario!+%f
%Feature! = Feature:%OptDesc!%Description!%e
%OptDesc! = %n|%ReqDesc!
%Description! = (?:%w\S.*%n)+

%Rule! = %wRule:%ReqDesc!%e
%ReqDesc! =  \S.*%n

%Background! = %wBackground:\n%Description2!%e
%Description2! = (?:%w%w\S.*%n)+

%Scenario! = %wScenario:%ReqDesc!%Given!%When!*%e
%Given! = %w%wGiven%ReqDesc!
%When! = %w%w(?:When|Then|And)%ReqDesc!

// indentation (empty)
%w = 
// empty lines
%e = \n*(?!\n)
// line of EOF
%n = (?:\n|%f)
// EOF
%f = $
```

with result of https://regex101.com/r/PhSdY7/1

```
^\n*(?!\n)Feature:(?:(?:\n|$)|(?: \S.*(?:\n|$)))(?:(?:\S.*(?:\n|$))+)\n*(?!\n)(?:Rule:(?: \S.*(?:\n|$))\n*(?!\n))?(?:Background:\n(?:(?:\S.*(?:\n|$))+)\n*(?!\n))?(?:Scenario:(?: \S.*(?:\n|$))Given(?: \S.*(?:\n|$))(?:(?:When|Then|And)(?: \S.*(?:\n|$)))*\n*(?!\n))+$
```

Comment: The markup appears to be wrong in the regex101 link. Text below it is indented. I would want this to work if none of the text was indented.

Also how did you generate this solution?

Comment: As I was traveling and time is about to expire on the bounty I will award it as no other answer was given by the community.

Comment: It also would not have a $ at the end of the text. The text would just end.

Can you share how I would add a test case in that link?

Comment: I was able to make some adjustments to the regex that appear to get close to working except it fails at the end of text unless there is a newline. I would want it to match the below test case:

https://regex101.com/r/hbLJc3/6

Comment: @Shawn 1. As far as I understood, Gherkin requires consistent indentation. If that's not correct please tell me the correct implementation. 1.1. I will change indentation to empty, it'll just work as you've seen. 1.2 I did generate the solution with the snippet in the bottom of input. It searches for %x things, takes %0 and replaces %smth until all are replaced.

Comment: @Shawn 2. Thanks. Honestly I answered this because I've already made the above regex compiler and wanted to see how far I can get with it. Seems pretty far for me. (There is a reason people don't use regexes of this scale - they don't have a compiler /joking (and debugging is impossible))

Comment: @Shawn 3. Due to the way compiler works by taking the input text as input, I had to make something to mark end of input. You don't need to test it, just replacing `$|\$` with `$` is enough

Comment: @Shawn 4. I did change newlines to accept EOF, see https://regex101.com/r/AniJrY/1 ( source at https://regex101.com/r/cq7E2D/1 )